# Inflate layout and edit it in code

Tags: android, popupwindow, layout-inflater

I have an android XML file with the following content:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relLay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivQuit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/imgquit"
        android:background="@null"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/btnYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btnyes"
        android:background="@null"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/btnNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btnno"
        android:background="@null"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want to inflate it and then edit the ImageButtons via code. I do this as followed:

Inflate XML:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quitgame, null);
```

Try editing an ImageButton:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivQuit);
ImageButton imgBtnYes = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
ImageButton imgBtnNo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnNo);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imgBtnYes.getLayoutParams();
relParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
imgBtnYes.setLayoutParams(relParams);
```

However as long as the three code lines with the LayoutParams are existent the PopupWindow I create with the inflated view does not appear. It seems that the error is hidden in this line

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imgBtnYes.getLayoutParams();
```

but I don't understand why.

Can anybody tell me why the PopupWindows does not appear because of this code line(s)?
Is it because of the PopupWindow itself or because of the LayoutInflater?

Comment: this `ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivQuit)` should be `ImageView imgView = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.ivQuit)` same for ImageButton's also.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works. I didn't even thought one second that the error could be hidden in that lines of code...

Comment: you are welcome for clarity i will post it as an answer so that you can accept the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quitgame, null);
```

Use the View object to initialize the views.

```
 ImageView imgView = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.ivQuit);
 ImageButton imgBtnYes = (ImageButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
 ImageButton imgBtnNo = (ImageButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
```

You can `findViewById` of the current view hierachy set to the activity. In your case you are inflating your layout. So use the inlfated view object to initialize your views.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating the layout with root set to null, so your layout variable (returned by the inflate method) holds the root of the inflated layout (in this case, your RelativeLayout). I didnt see the code where you are attaching the inflated layout to your activity's content (maybe the code you posted is not complete?).
Given this, your findViewById calls should return nulls. 
Moreover, as far as I know and understand, unless the view is attached to a view that is already somewhere in the activity, the LayoutParams are not going to be correct as no dimensions are set (even in case they are invoked on a view that isn't null, obviously).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first comment to my post already solved my problem. However another time thanks that you took your time to help me.